# GMSPolygon array iOS crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, google-maps, polygon

I Have an extremely strange issue with the GMSPolygon object. 
Just out of nowhere my code crashes with the error "Unrecognized selector send to instance 0x...."

(Yes it worked all day, and suddenly it starts crashing)

I am using an array of Polygons (to keep track of them and update them dynamically) and I initialize them as follows in my -viewDidLoad:

```
GMSPolygon *myPoly[50];
```

--

```
GMSMutablePath *path = [[GMSMutablePath alloc] init];
// set some fake coordinates, initializing a Polygon with an empty path seems to crash as well...

[path addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(1,0)];
[path addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-1,0)];
[path addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(0,1)];

for (int i=0;i<50;i++) {
    myPoly[i] = [GMSPolygon  polygonWithPath:path];
    myPoly[i].map = nil;
}
```

Later on in my program I try to acces the object again in the same way, first set it to nil so it will be removed from the map, and then update and if necessary display it again

```
for (int i=0;i<50;i++) {
    myPoly[i] = [GMSPolygon  polygonWithPath:path];
    myPoly[i].map = nil;  <--------- CRASH 


    // Do other stuf here, update the Polygon data and if needed
    // display again as follows:
    myPoly[i].map = mapView_;

}
```

But it seems to crash..
Same thing happens if I put the GMSPolygon in an NSMutable array. Initializing the array is fine, but getting the GMSPolygon out of the array and setting the .map property gives the same crash..

UPDATE:

It seems be caused by the object Memory locations.. If it works fine, memory locations are as follows:

[0] GMSPolygon *    0x1558ed750 0x00000001558ed750 <--- viewDidLoad for-loop

[0] GMSPolygon *    0x1558ed750 0x00000001558ed750 <--- other function for-loop

- When it crashes

[0] GMSPolygon *    0x12e7cbf30 0x000000012e7cbf30 <--- viewDidLoad for-loop

[0] GMSPolygon *    0x129d36630 0x0000000129d36630 <--- other function for-loop

The object is only initialized once in the viewDidLoad, nowhere else!
It obviously  explains the crash if the objects memory location are different.. but what's happening here?

Any one an idea why?

UPDATE 2, Got Crash log now:

```
2016-04-14 15:16:49.618 myApp[1130:240689] -[GMSMutablePath setMap:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1540bb560
2016-04-14 15:16:49.627 myApp[1130:240689] void uncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *__strong) [Line 354] CRASH: -[GMSMutablePath setMap:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1540bb560
2016-04-14 15:16:49.688 myApp[1130:240689] void uncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *__strong) [Line 355] Stack Trace: (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000182ebee50 <redacted> + 148
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000182523f80 objc_exception_throw + 56
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000182ec5ccc <redacted> + 0
3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000182ec2c74 <redacted> + 872
4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000182dc0d1c _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
5   myApp                               0x00000001001115a0 -[mapViewController plotPoly] + 2028
6   myApp                               0x000000010012c944 -[mapViewController mapView:didChangeCameraPosition:] + 556
7   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000182ec4ae0 <redacted> + 144
8   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000182dbc548 <redacted> + 284
9   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000182dc0e70 <redacted> + 60
10  myApp                              0x0000000100203370 -[GMSDelegateForward forwardInvocation:] + 108
11  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000182ec2aa4 <redacted> + 408
12  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000182dc0d1c _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
13  myApp                               0x0000000100188fec -[GMSMapView updateWithCamera:] + 176
14  Foundation                          0x0000000183893ffc <redacted> + 340
15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000182e75124 <redacted> + 24
16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000182e74bb8 <redacted> + 540
17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000182e728b8 <redacted> + 724
18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000182d9cd10 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
19  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000184684088 GSEventRunModal + 180
20  UIKit                               0x0000000188069f70 UIApplicationMain + 204
21  myApp                               0x000000010013dd3c main + 124
22  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000018293a8b8 <redacted> + 4)

2016-04-14 15:16:49.700 myApp[1130:240689] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[GMSMutablePath setMap:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1540bb560'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x182ebee38 0x182523f80 0x182ec5ccc 0x182ec2c74 0x182dc0d1c 0x1001115a0     
0x10012c944 0x182ec4ae0 0x182dbc548 0x182dc0e70 0x100203370 0x182ec2aa4 
0x182dc0d1c 0x100188fec 0x183893ffc 0x182e75124 0x182e74bb8 0x182e728b8 
0x182d9cd10 0x184684088 0x188069f70 0x10013dd3c 0x18293a8b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I am stunned now. 
The initial initialization works fine, the Polygons are drawn as the should, but as soon as I call the function to redraw the polygons, the crash happens.. and strange enough now I see why it crashes, but I don't understand.. It changes the first 5 array entry's to GMSMutablePath and GMSPolyLine , instead of GMSPolygon ?!, **see link to picture below**.. And have no idea why, because I am 100% sure the array of GMSPolygon is not touched anywhere else in the mean time..

[Picture of of change in Array type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7i5oh.png)

Comment: Don't store objective-c objects in C arrays, they don't retain their contents so they will get deallocated while they are still in the array

Comment: Ok, so do you have any idea how to deal with this. I am doing the same with markers, and that seems to work fine. Point is that I need to keep track of some of the objectes I put on the map as they are dynamic and I don't want to redraw the map every second or so..

Answer (score 0):

I can't post a comment yet due to my reputation. Just like what Dan said, use **NSArray** or **NSMutableArray** to store your objects. Then do your stuff.

UPDATE:
Here are my suggestions:

- Add All Exceptions to your breakpoint navigator.
- Try testing your code without loop.
- Try adding float values as your coordinates.

See example code below:

```
GMSMutablePath *prettyPoly = [GMSMutablePath path];
[prettyPoly addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.506191, 1.83197)];
[prettyPoly addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.05249, 1.650696)];
[prettyPoly addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.92225, 1.321106)];
[prettyPoly addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.996719, 1.219482)];
[prettyPoly addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.049112, 1.244202)];
[prettyPoly addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.197507, 1.334839)];
[prettyPoly addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.519564, 1.801758)];

GMSPolygon *polygon = [GMSPolygon polygonWithPath: prettyPoly];
polygon.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.25 blue:0 alpha:0.3];
polygon.strokeColor = [UIColor greenColor];
polygon.strokeWidth = 5;
polygon.map = self.googleMap;
```

If everything failed:
 - Refer to this doc: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_polygon#properties

- How about you try Polyline class and see this example: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/shapes#add_a_polyline
- Last, try seeking help from Google Forum, or from the repo of that library you are using.

Comment: But as mention in my question, same thing happend. If I initialize the GMSPolygon, do all the bits and pieces with it, store it in a NSMutableArray, and later take the object out and alter it, it also crashes..

Comment: Can you post the error log completely? I'm really trying to figure out your question although I have no experience in using google-maps.

Comment: I would love to but as it is intermitted, it now works. If I enable the Break on All Exceptions, it will break at  myPoly[i].map = nil; (in the for-loop in my other function) with the error Unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x....

Comment: Stupid question: Have you tried testing your code without a for loop? Also, I bet you already know this, when debugging, always add All Exceptions to breakpoint navigator. Another question: have you tried inputting float values to your coordinates? --- I'll update my answer to make my comments more readable.

Comment: I have the All Exception, that is why I see it crashes on the .map = nil line. I will change to floats, still if you look at the updated question and the attached picture, some strange things are happening..

Comment: I have updated my question, and I really did my best in helping you out. Check it out.

Comment: Unfortunately not prettygirl. As mentioned it is highly intermitted. Thanks for you extensive input, but single polygons work fine, it is just the Array of them that seems to cause issue.

Comment: For now it seems to be stable, I had some memory leaks in the program, not related to the Polygons though, but after fixing these it seemed to be stable for a while now..

Comment: That's good to know. You might want to select this answer as answer if you have solved the problem. Thanks.